# How to write and read Mac OS metada "WhereFrom" field? (Java)

Tags: java, macos, metadata

When downloading a file from Safari (on a Mac) one of the metadata fields is the "where from", it records the URL from which the file was downloaded (see [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRTF1.jpg)).

I am writing my own little web crawler and I was thinking to use this metadata field to record the file's origin.

I understand this metadata field is called com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms but I have no idea how to read/write it.

I'd highly appreciate any help on this matter!